# Color correction to my favorite movie

Tags: ffmpeg, script

I have found this script [removing green tint](https://lotrocommunity.com/forum/topic/3768-color-correctingremoving-green-tint-in-the-blu-ray-of-first-lord-of-the-rings-movie-the-fellowship-of-the-ring/)and i want to use it to color correct my blu ray copy, but i do not know how to use this script in ffmpeg. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The script you have found is manually adjusted to solve a very specific issue for a very specific movie. Are you asking about fixing "first Blu Ray for the Lord of the Rings trilogy" or other Blu Ray content?